# Why adding @RunWith annotation to my JUnit tests if they work as expected without it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I always add the `@SpringBootTest` to my test classes when using Spring Boot and my tests work as expected. I wonder what benefit do I get from also adding `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, since all over the internet that annotation is being used.

Comment: [This article at baelung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) might bring some light on the subject.

Comment: If you're using JUnit 4, and are using SpringBootTest without RunWith(SpringRunner.class), then the SpringBootTest annotation has no effect at all and is completely useless. If you're using JUnit 5, then RunWith is irrelevant, since it's a JUnit 4 annotation.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh, that's it! I'm using JUnit 5, indeed. Can you copy and paste your comment into an answer so I can select it as accepted answer?

Comment: To add to JBNizet's comment, the [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) annotation is itself annotated with JUnit 5's [`@ExtendWith`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtendWith.html) annotation. This makes use of so-called [composed annotations](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-meta-annotations).

Answer (score 1):

The `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` provides support for loading ApplicationContext and having beans `@Autowired` into your test instance.